# Cannot load font 'Press Start 2P' in SVG

Tags: svg, fonts

I have the following svg I need to render in as a standalone svg file:

```
<svg width="89" height="55" viewBox="0 0 89 55" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <style>
    @font-face {
        font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
        src: url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Press+Start+2P');
    }
    </style>
    <rect width="89" height="55" fill="black" />
    <rect x="5.5" y="5.5" width="78" height="44" fill="#0000FF" />
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="44.5" y="31" fill=" white" font-family="Press Start 2P" font-size="12" letter-spacing="0em">1234</text>
    <rect x="78" y="45" width="9" height="8" fill="#FF4F0A" />
    <rect x="5.5" y="5.5" width="78" height="44" stroke="#FF4F0A" stroke-width="3" />
    <path d="M81.4286 51V50.4286H81V49.8571H81.8571V50.4286H83.1429V49.2857H81.4286V48.7143H81V47.5714H81.4286V47H83.5714V47.5714H84V48.1429H83.1429V47.5714H81.8571V48.7143H83.5714V49.2857H84V50.4286H83.5714V51H81.4286Z" fill="#0000FF" />
</svg>
```

I am trying to use a given font (Press Start 2P) but it does not render, neither locally when I open the svg file nor with the following data uri

```
data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg%20width%3D%2289%22%20height%3D%2255%22%20viewBox%3D%220%200%2089%2055%22%20fill%3D%22none%22%20xmlns%3D%22http%3A//www.w3.org/2000/svg%22%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cstyle%3E%20%20%20%20%40font-face%20%7B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20font-family%3A%20%27Press%20Start%202P%27%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20src%3A%20url%28%27https%3A//fonts.googleapis.com/css%3Ffamily%3DPress%2BStart%2B2P%27%29%3B%20%20%20%20%7D%20%20%20%20%3C/style%3E%20%20%20%20%3Crect%20width%3D%2289%22%20height%3D%2255%22%20fill%3D%22black%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%3Crect%20x%3D%225.5%22%20y%3D%225.5%22%20width%3D%2278%22%20height%3D%2244%22%20fill%3D%22%230000FF%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%3Ctext%20text-anchor%3D%22middle%22%20x%3D%2244.5%22%20y%3D%2231%22%20fill%3D%22%20white%22%20font-family%3D%22Press%20Start%202P%22%20font-size%3D%2212%22%20letter-spacing%3D%220em%22%3E1234%3C/text%3E%20%20%20%20%3Crect%20x%3D%2278%22%20y%3D%2245%22%20width%3D%229%22%20height%3D%228%22%20fill%3D%22%23FF4F0A%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%3Crect%20x%3D%225.5%22%20y%3D%225.5%22%20width%3D%2278%22%20height%3D%2244%22%20stroke%3D%22%23FF4F0A%22%20stroke-width%3D%223%22%20/%3E%20%20%20%20%3Cpath%20d%3D%22M81.4286%2051V50.4286H81V49.8571H81.8571V50.4286H83.1429V49.2857H81.4286V48.7143H81V47.5714H81.4286V47H83.5714V47.5714H84V48.1429H83.1429V47.5714H81.8571V48.7143H83.5714V49.2857H84V50.4286H83.5714V51H81.4286Z%22%20fill%3D%22%230000FF%22%20/%3E%3C/svg%3E
```

#### EDIT

After comment, I tried to embed the whole font but still does not work

```
<svg width="89" height="55" viewBox="0 0 89 55" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
        <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: "Press Start 2P";
            src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,..) format("woff");
            font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;
        }
    </style>
    </defs>
    <rect width="89" height="55" fill="#E5E5E5" />
    <rect width="89" height="55" fill="#29296E" />
    <rect x="5.5" y="5.5" width="78" height="44" fill="#0000FF" />
    <text text-anchor="middle" x="44.5" y="31" fill=" white" font-family="Press Start 2P" font-size="12">
    {}azer
    </text>
    <rect x="5.5" y="5.5" width="78" height="44" stroke="#FF4F0A" stroke-width="3" />
    <rect x="47" y="45" width="41" height="8" fill="#FF4F0A" />
    <text text-anchor="end" x="86" y="52" fill=" white" font-family="Press Start 2P" font-size="8" letter-spacing="0em">
    {}
    </text>
</svg>
```

the base64 comes from the base64 encoding of the .ttf file

Comment: At the very least remember that `src` needs a `url` _and_ `format`. Might not solve the problem, but is very much required syntax. Also please explain whether this is "on a webpage" or "as a standalone SVG file", because the rules around what is allowed to load are very different between the two. (stand-alone SVG will never download additional content for obvious security reasons, so if you want a custom font for stand-alone, you need to give the font-face rule the base64 encoded data-uri as src, so that the entire font is embedded)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first example doesn't work since you're using a css URL as a font file URL.

**Open your google font URL and copy the actual `@font-face` rule**
The returned css depends on your current browser – yeah, user agent sniffing!

```
  @font-face {
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pressstart2p/v14/e3t4euO8T-267oIAQAu6jDQyK3nVivM.woff2) format('woff2');
  }
```

Otherwise use a service like [google web fonts helper](https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts) to get the actual font file URLs.

#### False friends: css properties vs. svg attributes

Svg's font related attributes like `font-family` apparently don't work well with css style definitions.

Better apply `font-family` within the `<style>` element like so:

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 89 55" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/pressstart2p/v14/e3t4euO8T-267oIAQAu6jDQyK3nVivM.woff2) format('woff2');
      }
      text {
        font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
        font-size: 12;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect width="89" height="55" fill="black" />
  <rect x="5.5" y="5.5" width="78" height="44" fill="#0000FF" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="44.5" y="31" fill=" white">1234</text>
  <rect x="78" y="45" width="9" height="8" fill="#FF4F0A" />
  <rect x="5.5" y="5.5" width="78" height="44" stroke="#FF4F0A" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

#### Embedded fonts

Some  services provide a way to generate/convert font files to base64 data URLs like [transfonter](https://transfonter.org)

**Embedded font example**

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 89 55" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <defs>
    <style>
      @font-face {
        font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
        font-style: normal;
        font-weight: 400;
        src: url('data:font/woff2;charset=utf-8;base64,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') format('woff2');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal;
      }

      text {
        font-family: 'Press Start 2P';
        font-size: 12;
      }
    </style>
  </defs>
  <rect width="89" height="55" fill="black" />
  <rect x="5.5" y="5.5" width="78" height="44" fill="#0000FF" />
  <text text-anchor="middle" x="44.5" y="31" fill=" white">1234</text>
  <rect x="78" y="45" width="9" height="8" fill="#FF4F0A" />
  <rect x="5.5" y="5.5" width="78" height="44" stroke="#FF4F0A" stroke-width="3" />
</svg>
```

If your svg only uses google webfonts, you can also try [vecta's nano optimiser](https://vecta.io/nano) – it can retrieve these fonts and include them as font subsets ( including only needed characters/glyphs).

Comment: awesome thanks! I used the transformer to convert again; it seems like you base64 was only for numbers