# Load font family into a SVG

Tags: html, svg, next.js, fonts

I'm trying to use a SVG file into a nextjs project, inside this SVG there's some text with some font that doesn't get loaded.

svg :

```html
<svg>
...
<text x="194.798px" y="83.058px" style="font-family:'Hopscotch';font-size:46.254px;fill:rgb(191,191,190);">U</text>
...
</svg>
```

Here the font-family is 'Hopscotch', but it is not properly loaded when rendering the svg into an html `img` snippet.

I do have the font definition in a ttf file. Do you know how I could give it to the svg so that he can read it properly?

**EDIT :**

I've added in the `defs` some css code with the link to the font file but it still doesn't work.

```html
<defs>
            <style>
                @font-face {
                    font-family: 'Hopscotch';
                    src: url('Hopscotch.ttf') format('truetype');
                }
                .R {
                    font-family:'Hopscotch';
                    font-size:63.176px;
                    fill:rgb(191,191,190);
                }
                .U {
                    font-family:'Hopscotch';
                    font-size:46.254px;
                    fill:rgb(191,191,190);
                }
            </style>
            ...
    </defs>
            <g transform="matrix(0.594954,-0.0231214,0.0103852,1.32459,-10.8795,-4.77331)">
                <text x="176.881px" y="82.794px" class="R">R</text>
            </g>
```

With this code, the text still have it's default font.
The file `Hopscotch.ttf`is located in the same dir as the svg.

Comment: You need to embed your custom font as a data-URL to use it in an `<img>` element. See related question ["Cannot load font 'Press Start 2P' in SVG"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73083188/cannot-load-font-press-start-2p-in-svg/73087065#73087065)